# problem about mean value theorem and definite integral

Tags: calculus, integration

here is a function $f(x) = x^2+1$, I learn that
$$f'(x) = \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$$
from the mean value theorem to derived its relation with integral.

What I was trying to do is to find the area under the function in interval of $[-1,2]$. I know you can simply solve this
$$ \int_{-1}^2  x^2+1$$
to obtain the area, but when I calculate $f'(x)$ using the $[f(b)-f(a)]/[b-a]$, I obtain $f'(x) = 1$, then I was trying to find $x$ using $2x=1$, I obtain $x=0.5$, when I plug $x$ into $f(0.5)(2+1) = [F(2)-F(-1)]$, I got $3.75=6$

Is there a misconception about
$$f'(x) = \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$$
can be integrated both side to obtain
$$f(x) = \frac{F(b)-F(a)}{b-a} = \frac{\int f(x)dx}{b-a}$$
which is how integral can be derived from mean value theorem?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Please review the *complete statement* (not just a formula out of the blue) of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem And *independently*, calculate your integral in the easy and usual way and include this calculation in your post (and [format your formulas](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation)).

Comment: okay thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first equality is incorrect. It is not $$f'(x)=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}.$$  I think you are confusing the mean value theorem and the definition of the derivative. You do not use the mean value theorem to calculate the derivative.

The definition of the derivative is $$f'(a)=\lim_{b\to a}\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}.$$  **This is not a formula where you plug in one specific value for** $a$ **and one specific value for** $b$ **and do one calculation. It is a limit.**

The mean value theorem says that if $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$, then there exists $c\in (a,b)$ such that $$f'(c)=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}.$$ **This is a formula for one specific value of** $a$ **and one specific value of** $b$. **This does not tell you what** $c$ **is or how to find it. Only that it exists. So you cannot use this formula to evaluate** $f'(c)$ **(or** $f'(x)$**)**.

Ultimately, the mean value theorem can be applied to the function $F(x)=\int_a^x f(t)dt$ to say that there exists some $c\in (a,b)$ such that $$f(c)=\frac{\int_a^b f(x)dx}{b-a}.$$  But, again, you do not know what the value of $c$ is, and there is no way to solve for it. I don't know how you came up with $x=.5$ in your answer, but it isn't what you should be doing. Since there is no way to know what the value of $c$ is which makes this equation true, it cannot be used to evaluate the integral.

Also, if you want to evaluate the integral $\int_a^b f(x)dx$, there is no reason why you should be calculating $f'(x)$.

Comment: thanks! I think I got it now after reading your answer and wiki definition